# no segments* file found in Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory@

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, lucene, lucene.net

I've downloaded some samples of Lucene.Net library and tried to run but it always throw this error

`no segments* file found in Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory@`

It throws an error while creating object at this line,

```
var searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory, false)
```

Is anyone has idea on this?
Is there any configuration required to implement this lucene.Net library?

Comment: Can you show your code that creates an index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it was two issue, 1st this is index was not created so for the 1st time it was throwing this error, Following code resolved that issue.

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(indexDirectory).Any()) 
{
     return new List<Model>();
}
```

2nd thing,

Do not forget to dispose object of `IndexSearcher`,`IndexReader` and `IndexWriter`.

Disposing memory of these object in sequence, resolved my issue.

Comment: how can i dispose object of IndexSearcher,IndexReader and IndexWriter ?